# validate_on_submit() adds extra fields to FieldList (Flask, WTForms)

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm rendering a list of MultipleSelect fields depending on what's in my database.

It renders fine, but on submitting the form and calling validate_on_submit() it changes the names of FieldList entries and appends extra entries. On first render, for example the ids are "systems_select-0", "systems_select-1", etc. On submit they're "systems_select-3",etc.

Code to populate fields:

```
systems_select = FieldList(SelectMultipleField(choices=[]), label=u'Select Systems to Run')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.populate_fields()

def populate_fields(self):
    for ii in range(0,len(racks)):
        self.systems_select.append_entry()
        entry = self.systems_select.entries[ii]
        entry.label = racks[ii]
        systems = get_systems(racks[ii])
        system_list = [(x,x) for x in systems]
        entry.choices = system_list
```